# How to layout a tabbed div

Tags: templating, entry

After playing around with Craft CMS for awhile I'm a little curious how some of you would approach this.

How would you add a tabbed div to an entry?

An example of the tab div below, it's the first example in the Bourbon Refill framework site.

[Bourbon Refills](http://refills.bourbon.io/)

Thanks

Comment: Hi Spheriri! Please consider accepting Fyrebase's answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this by using a Matrix field for complex content or the awesome Super Table field for something a little more basic

Depending on how complicated the content is you are putting in the tabs would determine if you would use either the Matrix or Super Table fields respectively.

Take a look at the Super Table plugin if you aren't already using it.

https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable